# istream exception mask and handling

Tags: c++, exception, iostream

If I have the following code

```
istream in{filename}; // file name is file you want to open.
in.exceptions(ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit);
```

Will the exception be looking for only the `failbit` and the `badbit`? If they're simply setting a flag, shouldn't that be done with `clear(ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit)`. Additionally, if I am using this method, I should enclose the calling function with a try catch, otherwise the exception will break the code?

Comment: I don't understand the question, if you're asking if `clear` can throw, yes it can. If you're asking why `clear` isn't used to set the exception mask, it's because the error state is separate from exceptions in streams because not everyone wants to use them. As for calling a function that can throw, you'll eventually want to catch the exception because otherwise your program will `terminate`. Where you catch it depends entirely on where you think you can handle the exception, which might not be in the immediate calling function.

Comment: Yes, it will only look for `failbit` and `badbit`; it won't set the flags but will throw an exception when the flags *are* set (or if they are already set). You should put the code that can set the flag in a try catch block.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the exception be looking for only the failbit and the badbit?

Yes. The call to `exception()` sets an internal member. If the state of the stream changes so that a flag is set that matches a flag that was set with exception then the stream will throw an excption.

> If they're simply setting a flag, shouldn't that be done with clear(ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit).

Its setting a different flag.
Basically you have two flags. The `state` flag and the `exception` flag. When a function changes the state flag it also does a comparison with the exception flag.

Think of it like this.

```
 // NOTE: This is not the real code.
 //       Think of this as the logical way it works.
 void setstate(iostate state)
 {

          rdstate = rdstate | state;
          // Check if we have 
          if (rdstate & exception()) {
              throw Bla{1};
          }
      }
 }
```

> Additionally, if I am using this method, I should enclose the calling function with a try catch

If you want to handle the exception locally (or report and error) then yes.

> otherwise the exception will break the code?

Break is the wrong word.
If you do not handle an exception and it escapes main the application will be terminated. But that is a good thing.